# How to remove ripple effect using tailwind css in react?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to remove the ripple effect of a button in tailwind CSS in react.

This is how it looks!
[ripple effect video](https://icecreamapps.com/v/h2xnnbn)

```
<button className="uppercase tracking-[0.4em] text-[color:hsl(36,100%,99%)] py-4 px-10 bg-[color:hsl(5,85%,63%)] mt-8 mb-0 rounded text-base">
                {children}
</button>
```

I have searched questions related to it all over the stack overflow but those were the ionic framework that I didn't want.
Is there any way to go with the `@layer` option?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/KWRh43hJqo / there is no ripple on the button on the native ; try it on another browers to see if it's due to the browser or device youre on

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using microsoft edge and when I'm trying to resize in mobile screen then it gives me the ripple effect. why is it so? and also while trying to click on moblie device. but yes it's not appearing in tailwind play